# Ignore horizontal mouse scrolling with nested ScrollViewer

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a ScrollViewer around a Grid to vertically scroll it's content.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    ...
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Inside of this Grid i have another Scrollviewer with horizontal content.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    ...
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Name="ButtonRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="ButtonRight_Tapped" />
    <Button Name="ButtonLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="ButtonLeft_Tapped" />
<Grid>
```

The `HorizontalScrollMode` is disabled and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is hidden because with mouse input, i want to scroll the content with the left/right buttons. The `HorizontalScrollMode` is disabled to prevent horizontal scrolling when the mouse is inside the ScrollViewer.

```
private void ButtonRight_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    ScrollViewer.ChangeView(ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + ScrollViewer.ActualWidth, 0, 1);
}
```

With this configuration i can scroll the page vertically even when the mouse is inside the horizontal ScrollViewer. Here is an image to give you an idea:
[image]

> The problem is with touch. How can i still scroll horizontally when the user is using a touch device? When i enable `HorizontalScrollMode` touch works as desired, but with a mouse it scrolls horizontally which i try to prevent.

Is there a way to ignore the horizontal scrolling with nested ScrollViewers?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.ishorizontalscrollchainingenabled.aspx)

Comment: How is `IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled` supposed to work? When i set it to false on the child scrollviewer there is no difference, horizontal scrolling is still enabled.

Comment: Did you use it as an attached property?

Comment: No, i just added it to the child ScrollViewer like `<ScrollViewer IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" ...>`. On what element should i put the attached property?

Comment: The docs are always a good place to start, the child. If I have time later I'll make a sample and test.

Comment: The docs don't really say much about the function of scroll chaining. I can put it on any of my objects and i don't see a change in behavior.

Comment: This has nothing to do with scroll chaining. The question is about preventing scrolling via mouse while still allowing scrolling via touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty simple solution to solve my problem.

I've added a `PointerEntered` to my nested horizontal ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer" PointerEntered="ScrollViewerImages_PointerEntered" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
...
</ScrollViewer>
```

and enabled the `HorizontalScrollMode` when the PointerDeviceType is Touch.

```
private void ScrollViewerImages_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Touch)
        ScrollViewerImages.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    else
        ScrollViewerImages.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
}
```