# ScrollViewer is not working properly with the combination of several GridViews within a ListView in an UWP App

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using `GridViews` representing files of different folders. Those `GridViews` with one row and horizontal orientation are orderd within an vertical `ListView`.

Here you get an idea from code:

```
<ListView ItemSource={Binding CollectionOfFolders}>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <GridView>

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Loaded="WrapGridLoaded"
                           MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"
                           Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                ...
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

And a visual impression here:

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is the handling of the vertical and horizontal scrolling.

With toch input everythings works as **desired**: When you move your finger up and down, you scroll through the listview (the folders). If you move your finger horizontally your scroll through the GridView (files).

**The problem** comes, when using a mouse wheel or touchpad with the two finger sroll gesture: When the pointer is on any item or file respectivley, it doesn't affect the ListView. All gestures do affect the gridview only.

I tried to disable and enable the vertical and horizontal scrollmodes, the IsVertical/HorizontalModeChanningEnabled property and also the effects of the scroll bar and scroll rail visibility.

I fount these questions related to the problem, but could find a solution for this specific problem I just decriped:

- [Ignore horizontal mouse scrolling with nested ScrollViewer](http://Ignore%20horizontal%20mouse%20scrolling%20with%20nested%20ScrollViewer)
- [ScrollViewer IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled and IsHorizontalRailEnabled functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338633/scrollviewer-ishorizontalscrollchainingenabled-and-ishorizontalrailenabled-funct)

It would be great if anybody does have ideas or even a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem comes, when using a mouse wheel or touchpad with the two finger sroll gesture: When the pointer is on any item or file respectivley, it doesn't affect the ListView. All gestures do affect the gridview only.

The problem is that the `GridView` item would capture the mouse wheel and double point scroll gesture when it focused. For your requirement, you could disable this feature manually.

You can use the inner `GridView` item `PointerEntered` and `ViewChanged` event to achieve this effect. When the inner `GridView` item scrolls to top or bottom make it `ScrollMode` be Disabled, meanwhile we make the inner `GridView` item `ScrollMode` be Enabled when the pointer enter into the inner `GridView` item.

And I found the [similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/767ce4bd-a7ed-49ad-bc80-9d9e39032952/uwpscroll-parent-view-when-inner-scroll-is-completed?forum=wpdevelop) in msdn and it has complete reply that you could refer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to adjust the solution you linked to my code. There is problem with the ScrollViewer of the GridView. You cannot resieve the ViewChanged Method or at least i couldn't fin a solution.

Comment: **Your suggestion of disabling the SrollMode once a certain event occures is a good idea.** I found the **PointerWheelChanged** event, which has a property for recognizing horizontalMousWheel (and touch) actions. The GridView doesn't have this event (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview)). But a ListView has. I keep you updated about my process.

Comment: I have to correct myself. The PointerWheel Changed event doesn't bubble up for a ListView neither (see [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview))

Comment: Do you find the final solution?